# Proof the inequality of Gamma function $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\geq N! \,\bigg|\Gamma\left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, gamma-function

To Show that the below complex integral vanishes

$$\int_{-\left(N+\frac{1}{2} \right)-i \infty}^{-\left(N+\frac{1}{2} \right)+i \infty}\Gamma(s) \,z^{-s}\,ds$$

[Bruce C. Berndt](https://experts.illinois.edu/en/publications/rudiments-of-the-theory-of-the-gamma-function) uses the inequality

$$\bigg|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|\geq N! \,\bigg|\Gamma\left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|$$

He proceeds as following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\left(N+\frac{1}{2} \right)-i \infty}^{-\left(N+\frac{1}{2} \right)+i \infty}\Gamma(s) \,z^{-s}\,ds&=O\left(\frac{1}{N!}\int_{-1}^{1}\bigg|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|\,\big|z\big|^{N+\frac{1}{2}} \,dt \right)\\ & +O\left(\frac{1}{N!}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi t}\,\big|z\big|^{N+\frac{1}{2}}\,e^{t(\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta)} \,dt \right)\\
&=O\left(\frac{\big|z\big|^{N+\frac{1}{2}}}{N!} \right)+O\left(\frac{\big|z\big|^{N+\frac{1}{2}}}{N!} \int_1^\infty\,e^{-\delta t}\,dt\right)\\
&=O\left( \frac{\big|z\big|^{N+\frac{1}{2}}}{N!}\right)\\
&=O(1)
\end{aligned}
$$

I am trying to prove this inequality. By the Gamma´s function functional equation we can write

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+it \right)&=\left(\frac{1}{2}-1+it \right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-1+it \right)\\
&=\left(-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\\
&= \cdots \\
&=\left(-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}+it \right) \cdots \left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\Gamma\left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Taking modulus

$$
\begin{aligned}
\bigg|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|&=\bigg|\left(-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}+it \right) \cdots \left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\Gamma\left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|\\
&=\bigg|\left(-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|\bigg|\left(-\frac{3}{2}+it \right)\bigg| \cdots \bigg|\left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|\bigg|\Gamma\left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+t^2 }\,\,\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+t^2} \,\,\cdots \,\, \sqrt{N^2+N+\frac{1}{4}+t^2 }\,\,\bigg|\Gamma\left(-N-\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\bigg|\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now I got stuck in how to proceed

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+t^2 }\,\,\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+t^2} \,\,\cdots \,\, \sqrt{N^2+N+\frac{1}{4}+t^2 }\geq 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots N $$

It doesn´t seem to make sense to me.
Can someone give a Hint on how to finish the proof?

Comment: Shouldn't $t$ vary between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ instead of $-1$ and $1$ in your first $O$-estimate?

Comment: Note that $$
\sqrt {\frac{1}{4} + t^2 }  \cdots \sqrt {N^2  + N + \frac{1}{4} + t^2 }  \ge \sqrt {\frac{1}{4}}  \cdots \sqrt {N^2  + N + \frac{1}{4}} \\ = \frac{1}{2} \cdots \left( {N + \frac{1}{2}} \right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)! \ge N!
$$ for $N\geq 3$.

Comment: @Gary thank you for your reply. The last step, how did you get? I see  $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdots\left(N+\frac{1}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{2^N}(2N+1)!!$, theh how do you get the last step?

Comment: Use $$
N! < \frac{{\left( {N + \frac{1}{2}} \right)!}}{{\sqrt {N + \frac{1}{2}} }}
$$ by http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E4

Comment: @Gary thank you, I got it from the inequality $(2n-1)!!=2^n\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+n \right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Comment: Or you just multiply and divide by $\Gamma(1/2)$.

Comment: @Ricardo770 Just curious is there a link with the Riemann's hypothesis ?

Comment: @ErikSatie as far as I am concerned no. This is related to the Inverse mellin transform of $\Gamma(s)$ using a rectangular contour. This integral is the integral over the vertical line on the left side of the contour as $N \to \infty$.